# chart js legend template

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I'm trying to make some custom templates for legends in chart js. After looking at some examples I am roughly familiar with the syntax but the one thing I need to know is how to get the values for the data that is passed in when making the chart. I have this template currently,

```
"<% var segment_sum = 0;%>" +
"<% for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) { segment_sum += data[i].value; }%>" +
        "<ul><% for (var i=0; i<segments.length; i++){%>" +
                "<li>" +
                    "<span style=\"color:<%=segments[i].fillColor%>\" class=\"legend-num\">" +
                        "<%=  Math.round(data[i].value / segment_sum * 100) %>" +
                    "</span>" +
                    "<span class=\"legend-percent\">" +
                        "%" +
                    "</span>" +
                    "<span class=\"legend-divider\">" +
                        "|" +
                    "</span>" +
                    "<span class=\"legend-label\">" +
                        "<img src=\"/content/img/star.png\" />" +
                    "</span>" +
                "</li>" +
             "<% } %>" +
         "</ul>";
```

I found out that I can use the variable "data" that I had declared locally but this makes the template less reusable because someone would have to name their dataset "data" specifically. Does segments have a field for getting the data values?

Answer (score 0):

You can access the data from the chart elements collection. For example, for a pie chart you could do

```
myPieChart.segments.forEach(function (segment) {
    console.log(segment.value)
})
```

Likewise each chart type has a collection. Look for the `update()` method under the Prototype methods section for the chart type in http://www.chartjs.org/docs